# Document control

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm looking for a way to allow a group of users to upload documents which are then locked so only a small group of users (i.e.management) can make changes. The files need to be uploaded with Metadata and i've not find a way to do it purely with access permissions.
any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: Have a look into Workflows; they should allow you to define what happens when with documents...

Comment: I'll have a look at that in more depth but at the moment I don't get the options to use the 'change item permissions' action in SPD even using 2010 work flows.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the required reputation to comment. My answer:
With SharePoint Designer Workflows, you have the option of using Impersonation Step. Use Impersonation Step to modify the permission at the document level. Create a group which will contain the users from management. Using Impersonation, remove all the permissions associated to the document and add only the newly created group.